# Perl recursion through filesystem (without File:Find) follows "top" one path only

Tags: perl, file, recursion, rename

The general problem: Iterate through a windows folder structure, without the use of Find::File and rename all folders to be some short value.  This is intended to fix the classic "windows file paths are more then 256 characters" problem.

My problem: I've got everything working, except that it will correctly process a single path through the tree, but not any others and I can't see why.

Note: use File:Find is still present, though not used, and the code is likely in-elegant.  It renames the current folder, then iterates through subfolders.

Code:

```
use strict;
use File::Find;
use File::Copy;
use File::Path;

my $target = "E:\\bl10s\\";

opendir( DIR, $target );
my $newFolderName = 0;

my $file;

while ( $file = readdir(DIR) ) {

    # A file test to check that it is a directory
    # Use -f to test for a file
    next if ( $file eq "." );
    next if ( $file eq ".." );
    next if ( -f "$target\\$file" );

    print "$target/$file" . "\n";

    while ( -e $target . $newFolderName ) {
        $newFolderName++;
    }

    print $target. $file . " rename to " . $target . $newFolderName . "\n";

    rename( $target . $file, $target . $newFolderName );

}

closedir(DIR);
opendir( DIR, $target );

while ( $file = readdir(DIR) ) {
    next if ( $file eq "." );
    next if ( $file eq ".." );
     if ( -f "$target\\$file" )
    {
        print "Failed name check on itterator main line \n";
    }
    my $nextDirectoryPathCalled = $target . $file;
    print "Re-iterating on:   " . $nextDirectoryPathCalled;
    my $someint = &stripper($nextDirectoryPathCalled);
}
closedir(DIR);

# find( \&dir_names, $target );

sub stripper {
    print "\nNew level\n";
    print "$_[0] . \n";



        my $target = $_[0] . "\\";

        opendir( DIR, $target );
        my $newFolderName = 0;

        my $file;

        while ( $file = readdir(DIR) ) {

            # A file test to check that it is a directory
            # Use -f to test for a file
            next if ( $file eq "." );
            next if ( $file eq ".." );
            next if ( -f "$target\\$file" );

            print "TARGET:  $target       FILE:  $file" . "\n";

            while ( -e $target . $newFolderName ) {
                $newFolderName++;
            }

            print $target
              . $file
              . " rename to "
              . $target
              . $newFolderName . "\n";

            rename( $target . $file, $target . $newFolderName );

        }

        closedir(DIR);




        opendir( DIR, $target );

        while ( $file = readdir(DIR) ) {
            next if ( $file eq "." );
            next if ( $file eq ".." );
            next if ( -f "$target\\$file" );

            my $nextDirectoryPathCalled = $target . $file;
            print "Re-iterating on:   " . $nextDirectoryPathCalled;
            &stripper($nextDirectoryPathCalled);

        }
        closedir(DIR);



}
```

Any ideas?  Feel free to be critical...

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you want to use `File::Find`? You even imported it…. You are running into problems because you use a *global* dirhandle – `opendir my $dir, ...` instead. You have no error handling. There is lots of repeated code, and signs of cargo-culting.

Comment: Yes, please explain why you don't want to use `File::Find`. It is fully functional and debugged. If you are trying to learn a little Perl, then I suggest you don't do it with real work on a live file structure. For your purposes I suggest you use the short filename (8.3 filename) for the path segments. These apply at the same time as the long filename, as long as SFN support has been enabled on your installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When doing recursion, it is important that each level has its own set of variables, and does not change those of upper levels. Take for example this implementation of the factorial, which is:

> *fac(n) = 1 · 2 · 3 · … · n*

In naïve Perl code, we could write

```
sub fac {
  $n = shift;
  return 1 if $n < 2;
  return $n * fac($n-1);
}
```

Output for `fac(10)` is `1`. This is cleary wrong, we expected `1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9*10 = 3628800`.

The problem is that each recursion level assigned to the same `$n` variable. We have the following call stack:

```
fac(10)
  $n = 10
fac(9) * $n
  $n = 9
fac(8) * $n * $n
  $n = 8
...
fac(1) * $n * $n * $n * $n * $n * $n * $n * $n * $n * $n
  $n = 1
  return 1
```

So all of that evaluates to `1`. Duh.

We can give each level a different `$n` variable by declaring it with `my`:

```
sub fac {
  my $n = shift;
  return 1 if $n < 2;
  return $n * fac($n-1);
}
```

Now, everything works as expected.

---

In Perl, bareword filehandles are global variables. When you do

```
opendir DIR, $somepath;
```

then you assign a handle to that global bareword. While recursing, you constantly reassign to it. When your function returns from a lower level, the handle does not get the previous value back.

Instead, you should use lexical variables for your handles as well:

```
opendir my $dir, $somepath;
```

Then each invocation of your subroutine has its own, non-global dirhandle, and everything should work as expected.

---

Using `File::Find` handles all of that complexity behind the scenes, and just makes the correct element directly available to your callback. It is robust, widely used, so you should really see if you shouldn't be using the `find` function from that module instead.

Comment: The reason not to use File::Find - it fails the moment it hits the 256 character windows limit.  At which point it falls over without grace.

No way to stop it that I've found.

Comment: @user2702772 Why do you think it "falls over without grace"? That might be the correct conclusion, but we don't know that. Give us facts.

Comment: Definition of fails without grace:
"Can't cd to .. from E:\my_very_long_file_path_more_then_256_long at C:/Perl64/lib/File/Find.pm line 803."

Comment: Quick hack for the `File::Find` problem: can you use the `no_chdir` option?

Comment: Nope, not an  option for this - or I certainly can't see how that would be enough.

Comment: Amon's answer is correct - DIR was a global, not lexical variable.

Once this was altered, there was magic.  Thanks.

Comment: @user2702772 Did that graceless fail occur before or after you tried to change the name of a directory? I.e. if you iterate over a list of directories, and then you change one dirname, and later try to cd to the old name, then you will fail.

Comment: That graceless fail happened before any changes had been written to disk - File::Find is simply not the tool to handle filenames longer then the OS handles well.

Comment: @SlavenRezic As an aside: Thank you for improving the File::Find diagnostics in future versions.